# How can i call from ListView.builder this MyIcons.data Dart(OOP)?

Tags: dart

**can i call from ListView.builder this MyIcons.data there is my icons**

```
abstract class MyIcons {
  static const String catalog = 'assets/icons/svg/catalog.svg';
  static const String shop = 'assets/icons/svg/shop.svg';
  static const String car = 'assets/icons/svg/car.svg';}
```

**There is im calling MyIcons.data**

```
ListView.builder(
                itemCount: data.length,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemBuilder: ((context, index) => Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        OutlinedButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: SvgPicture.asset(MyIcons.data[index]["icon"],))]));
```

Comment: Addition 

 List<Map<String, String>> data = [
    {"name": "Каталог", "icon": "catalog", "color": "catalogColor"},
    {"name": "Магазины", "icon": "shop", "color": "shopColor"},
    {"name": "Авто", "icon": "car", "color": "carColor"},]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
  child: SvgPicture.asset('aasets/icons/svg/${data[index]["icon"]}.svg',))]));
```